# Setting folder permissions in Windows via PHP

Tags: php, windows, permissions, filesystems

Is there a way to properly set folder permissions via PHP on a Windows filesystem, such as granting `user A` full access, and `user B` read-only on folder `\\fileserver\shares\users\A\`

I can't seem to find any PHP functions for Windows filesystems for PHP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Despite using the Unix file permission syntax, PHP's [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function does work in Windows (I just tested it).

If your user A was the file owner and user B wasn't then it would be easy to grant one set of permissions to user A and different permissions to user B. You can set the owner of a file using the [`chown()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) function (again, Unix-like syntax, but works with Windows, subject to your PHP program having sufficient permissions to itself to make the change).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to call command-line processes, you could use [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/) (if you need very detailed control) otherwise, CACLS is built in.

Comment: I believe it is doable without 3rd party tools (i.e., Windows should have native command-line commands/programs for this).

Comment: On Windows 7, running `cacls` says that it is deprecated and that `icacls` should be used instead.