# Gettext doesn't work on my localhost

Tags: php, localhost, gettext

I tried to start with gettext() but it doesn't work on my localhost.

My simple code:

```
<?php
$language='en';
putenv("LANG=$language"); 
setlocale(LC_ALL,$language);

$domain='test';
bindtextdomain($domain,"languages"); 
textdomain($domain);

echo _("Simple string to translate");
```

I have folder languages and in this folder another folder en but files are not creating. Thanks for help

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything,

Comment: 1) The files are not supposed to create themselves, you have to create the .po file and compile it to .mo using the msgfmt command.

2) Please show exactly what your folders are.

3) Verify that the locale you are trying to use exists on your system. (In console, execute "locale -a" to see a list).

Comment: Added and i don't see any errors, only "Simple string to translate". In my xampp folder htdocs/languages/en is empty.

Comment: Also check for folder permissions settings.

Comment: Naomi: http://i.imgur.com/RRcVB2B.png - my windows console doen't have "locale -a" command :< | Fred -ii - how can i check it on windows? Other scripts creating files without any problems

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/6732934/ on how to set folder permissions.

Comment: You usually need an external tool to create the .po file from your php scripts. Most people use xgettext, which is included in Poedit (http://poedit.net/).

Comment: if you are using `wamp` try to restart all services, and as I had the same problem my conclusion is that gettext won't work perfectly on `windows` localhost, instead if you have a linux OS it must work. Check the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good solution to set up your languages and call the translations from `.po` files. PHP is reading only `.po` so make sure to have that file's extension. In addition test your `locale` system if it is supporting the `xy_XY` format or the `xy` format: under linux use this line: `locale -a` and you will check how the locale is writed and supported. Under windows: `check the system.io file`.

```
//get the location and set the languages
define('SESSION_LOCALE_KEY', 'ix_locale');
define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US');
define('LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM', 'lang');
define('WEBSITE_DOMAIN', 'messages');

if (array_key_exists(LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM, $_REQUEST)) {
    $current_locale = $_REQUEST[LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM];
    $_SESSION[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY] = $current_locale;
} elseif (array_key_exists(SESSION_LOCALE_KEY, $_SESSION)) {
    $current_locale = $_SESSION[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY];
} else {
    $current_locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE;
}

putenv("LC_ALL=$current_locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $current_locale);
bindtextdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang');
bind_textdomain_codeset(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8');
textdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN);
```