# chmod and mkdir (PHP on windows)

Tags: php, windows, chmod, mkdir

I am running php on an apache server on windows server 2012.

I have the following code:

```
mkdir("path...\".$reg->id, 0777)
```

I was told that the parameter mode is not valid on windows (the default value is 0777), so how do I have to specify the path permissions?

Hope you can understand me, English is not my first language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting folder permissions in Windows via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732934/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

Parameter 'mode' is ignored on Windows (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)). If you want to set permissions to files or folders on Windows, you may use **cacls.exe** through cmd or exec() function

Comment: Hi! is there any official documentation abot how to implement cacls.exe on php?